# How 'endsWith' and other string functions are being generated in ES5 code

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I got an error of **error TS2339: Property 'endsWith' does not exist on type 'string'** while transpile ts to js.

When I search on google about it, I got an answer of **'endsWith' is ES6 function, target ts compiler to ES6".**

I did the same, error gone. ES6 code generated.

the command was: `tsc file-name.ts --target ES6`

**BUT** if I did not target ES6, the error came, & still code transpile.

And I get valid ES.

As far as I know, until now, typescript is being transpile to ES5.

So, I get ES5 code because I did not target to ES6 at time of transpile.

the command was: `tsc file-name.ts`

**Note:** I removed the old .js file.

Then how 'endsWith' and other string functions are being generated in ES5 code? As they are ES6 function, and I did not target ES6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different sorts of things that new features of Javascript introduce: **syntax** and built-in **objects/methods**.

When you transpile (such as with Typescript, or from ESNext to ES5), you are translating the *syntax* of your code from its original version to ES5. For example:

```
const foo = 'foo'; // ES6 syntax
```

may become

```
var foo = 'foo';  // ES5 syntax
```

This does not affect *non-syntax* features. The following syntax is perfectly legal in ES5:

```
console.log(foo.endsWith('o'));
```

But just because the syntax is legal doesn't necessarily mean that what `foo` refers to has an `endsWith` property.

Those non-syntax features do not need **transpiling**, but rather, **polyfilling** - that is, if they do not exist in the environment, define them yourself. For example, one possible [polyfill for `endsWith` is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Polyfill):

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(search, this_len) {
    if (this_len === undefined || this_len > this.length) {
      this_len = this.length;
    }
    return this.substring(this_len - search.length, this_len) === search;
  };
}
```

If you make sure that the above code runs, you will not get the `Property 'endsWith' does not exist on type 'string'` error.

Most new objects/methods can be polyfilled, but some can't be, at least not fully accurately (eg `Symbol`s and `Proxy`x, IIRC).

A popular service which provides polyfills for many newer objects/methods is [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v3/).

To ensure that obsolete browsers can understand your code written in ESNext (or Typescript), use *both* transpilation *and* polyfills.